# RSpec - Testing strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, strong-parameters

I am using the `strong_parameters` gem in my controllers, but I'm having a hard time understanding how I would test it.

Here's an example of my setup

```
class UserController < ActionController::Base
  include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      ...
    end
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :username, :email)
  end
end
```

I want to test the `user_params` method to make sure that it is correctly filtering out malicious key/value pairs, but can't figure out how to do it.  Has anyone else been through this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can stub the params hash as

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new(your_hash)
```

This is the class that your URL params are being converted to in your controller, and it gives you the require and permit methods.

I personally extract the functionally out into a new class to handle the authorization policy.

Answer (score 6):

Modify this according to your need,

```
describe "create action" do
    it 'creates a user' do
      User.should_receive(:create).
        with({name: 'Alan D'}.with_indifferent_access)
      post :create, user:
        { first_name: 'Alan', last_name: 'Donald', username: 'alan77', email: 'mymail@yopmail.com' }
    end
end
```

or other alternative solution to this problem is:

```
describe UsersController::UserParams do
  it 'cleans the params' do
    params = ActionController::Parameters.new(user: {foo: 'bar', name: 'baz'})
    user_params = UsersController::UserParams.build(params)
    expect(user_params).to eq({name: 'baz'}.with_indifferent_access)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I would test `strong_parameters`, which I am guessing you're using via [the gem](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters).

The gem has [its own tests](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters/tree/master/test), so we can assume it works as expected.

This is an example of 'testing Rails', which I believe is unnecessary. I wouldn't test that `attr_accessible` works as advertised (Testing Rails), or `attr_accessor` (Testing Ruby).

IMHO, your integration tests should cover all desired instances of success/failure and implicitly cover your `strong_parameter` configuration.

Comment: Our test policy is to explicitly write tests for all functionality, to allow us to potentially switch gems/roll our own later on and still know that the system is working.

Comment: You can also be testing that your code that integrates in with strong_parameters is working properly.  I have fields which are writable/not writeable depending on user roles/permissions, so I need to test that these two pieces integrate properly.

Comment: Having taken an app from Rails 1.1 to 3.2 (and now preparing for 4.0), I can assure you that testing Rails is very necessary. Something that worked one way in one version of Rails may change behavior in another version. For instance, I used to clone activerecord records using the `clone` method, but somewhere between 3.0 and 3.2 they decided that `dup` would provide that functionality instead... and do it slightly differently. This was not well advertised, but it was quickly caught by my tests.

Comment: Yes @sockmonk - this is definitely one situation where you'd want to test Rails :)